# The results of ports scanning seem to be incorrect while using AsyncCallback

Tags: c#, winforms, asynccallback

I'm trying to port scan given IP address with range of 20 ports. I know that port 80 is open and all other are closed. My code is showing that all ports are open.

I'm trying to use asynchronous TCPClient to achieve port scan.

What could be wrong here? Have I missed something?

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int port = 80; port < 100; port++)
    {
        ScanPort(port);
    }
}

private void ScanPort(int port)
{
    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
    {
        client.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Parse("74.125.226.84"), port, new AsyncCallback(CallBack), client);
    }
}

private void CallBack(IAsyncResult result)
{
    using (TcpClient client = (TcpClient)result.AsyncState)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                txtDisplay.Text += "open" + Environment.NewLine;
            });
        }
        catch
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                txtDisplay.Text += "closed" + Environment.NewLine;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have now as CallBack method:

```
    private void CallBack(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        using (TcpClient client = (TcpClient)result.AsyncState)
        {
            client.EndConnect(result);

            if (client.Connected)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    txtDisplay.Text += "open" + Environment.NewLine;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    txtDisplay.Text += "closed" + Environment.NewLine;
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you catching? An error in setting the text to `open`?

Comment: @todda.speot.is, I'm trying to check if port is open or not. I know that with out using asynccallback I can use client.connected but not sure how to check in call back method. Thought this solution might work.

Comment: Yes, but the code sets the text to open and *if there's an exception in setting the text* will try and set the text to closed. Your code isn't checking to see whether a port is open or closed, it's just appending "open" and if that somehow fails appending "closed". You need to check whether `result` contains a failure or not.

Comment: @NewHelpNeeder you still need to modify the ScanPort method to so that it doesn't dispose the client, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement:

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
{
    client.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Parse("74.125.226.84"), port, new AsyncCallback(CallBack), client);
}
```

Creates a new TcpClient, then calls BeginConnect, and then immediately disposes the client, before reaching the callback. Keep in mind that the BeginConnect method is not blocking. The disposal of the client should only happen in the callback, so the ScanPort method should look like this:

```
private void ScanPort(int port)
{
    var client = new TcpClient();
    try {
        client.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Parse("74.125.226.84"), port, new AsyncCallback(CallBack), client);
    } catch (SocketException) {
        ...
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

In the callback you should also call [EndConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.endconnect.aspx):

```
using (TcpClient client = (TcpClient)result.AsyncState)
{
    try
    {
        client.EndConnect(result);
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            txtDisplay.Text += "open" + Environment.NewLine;
        });
    }
    catch
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            txtDisplay.Text += "closed" + Environment.NewLine;
        });
    }
```